# What does the word "bobbing" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, translation, literature

> They didn't meet anyone else until they reached the staircase up to
> the third floor. Peeves was bobbing halfway up, loosening the carpet
> so that people would trip.

*Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*

Does the word "bobbing" imply movement towards the middle of the stair, or movement up and down at the middle of the stair?

*Peeves is a **ghost**

Comment: Since Peeves is a *ghost*, he "bobs" up and down in the air on the staircase (like something floating on "choppy" water). His movement is ***up and down*** - nothing to do with "the middle" of the stairway (horizontally OR vertically). But somehow, his bumping / bobbing on the stair carpet is enough to loosen it (ghosts move in mysterious ways! :)

Comment: Look up the word in a dictionary before posting please.

Answer (score 2):

From Merriam-Webster:

> **bob** *intransitive verb*
> **1 a :** to move up and down briefly or repeatedly

Peeves is a ghost and cannot stand on stairs, but instead floats in the air with a periodic up-and-down movement.

If a non-ghost character had been loosening the carpet there, it would have read, "***standing** halfway up*" instead.